# When I click a button I want to hide an html table and show another html table in Alpine.js - Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am working in a Laravel 8 Livewire 2 project. There, when a button is clicked, I want to hide an html table and show another html table using Alpine.js. I am trying with below code in Livewire Blade, but not working. Please let me know what is wrong with my code. Please let me know how I can show an html table and hide another html table when button is clicked using Alpine.js in Laravel Livewire. Thanks in advance.

```
<div x-data="{id: 1}">
    <button @click="$dispatch('open-dropdown',{id})">Open Dropdown</button>
</div>
    
<table x-data="{ open: true }"
    x-show="open"
    @open-dropdown.window="if ($event.detail.id == 1) open = false"
    @click.away="open = true" class="table-fixed w-full" >
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-gray-100">
        <th class="px-4 py-2">Folder Name 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

  <table x-data="{ open: false }"
  x-show="open"
  @open-dropdown.window="if ($event.detail.id == 1) open = true"
  @click.away="open = false" class="table-fixed w-full" >
  <thead>
      <tr class="bg-gray-100">
          <th class="px-4 py-2">Folder Name 2</th>
      </tr>
 </thead>
 </table>
```

Comment: Your code is working. You can see the difference. Just set different table headers in the tables. ex. "Folder Name 1" and "Folder Name 2".

Comment: @DanielPetrovaliev, please look again. I changed the folder names as you suggested. The Folder Name 1 is always visible. After I click the button, Folder Name 1 table does not hide,  Folder Name 2 table shows up. Clicking again keeps the Folder Name 1 table and hide the Folder Name 2 table. Folder Name 2 table is working fine, just Folder Name 1 table does not hide at all. Thanks.

Comment: I've created a demo for you check it out: https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/e0ad0ac8-bf8c-4e21-918c-30e56a2f018f

Comment: @DanielPetrovaliev, thanks a lot for the demo. But when the page loads then first table Folder Name 1 is visible, then if you click on the button that goes away forever and table two Folder Name 2 becomes visible. Clicking again and again shows and hides the table two Folder Name 2, but table one Folder Name 1 is never visible again.

Comment: What's your use case? I didn't get it from the description.

Comment: @DanielPetrovaliev, use case is that, a first table and a button should be visible at the beginning. When that button is clicked first table should hide and second table should display. When the button is clicked again, the first table should show and second table should hide. I am not understanding about use case. Can you please give me an example of use case? So, I can explain it to you properly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got it now. If your use case is to have only two dropdowns the variable with an inverted conditional check will be the best solution for you. Check it out there: https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/fadebdc5-df52-4759-b749-a921ec894052

Comment: @DanielPetrovaliev thanks a lot for the answer. I am very sorry to reply you late as I was sick for a while. Thanks again and bye.